# Canvas Signed Request vs OAuth flow

Tags: oauth, canvas, webserverflow

What are the compelling reasons to choose one approach over the other? Is OAuth flow more secure than the Signed Request flow or is OAuth preferable only to have the external app invoke Salesforce via the auth token?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Signed request is completely secure while oauth flow is provided in case you want to do two way oauth and also alert the user that he is allowing access to the resources .

When you do an oauth flow ,you ask the User permission to allow access which is an added security .